# Error passing parameter to function react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Hello I'm using react with GoogleMaps and I'm trying to pass an index to the function onMarkerClick But it's not working for me. These 3 parameters are pass automatically (props, marker, e) But when I pass the index It give me an error.
And I don't understand why. I don't you if someone can help me.

This code is in the file App.js

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
    onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e, index) => {
        this.setState({
            defaultAnimation: null,
            showingInfoWindow: true,
            activeMarker: marker,
            selectedPlace: props
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            {this.state.AddressListMarkers.map((marker, index) => (
                <Marker
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => this.onMarkerClick(index)} 
                />
            ))}
        )
    }
}
```

I put also my git if can help you to test the code: 
https://github.com/Reyniergc/Neighborhood-Map-Builded-With-React.js

Thank you very much

Comment: what error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, you are getting undefined values for `marker`, `e` and `index` with the current code.

Calling onClick handler as below should fix the issue for you:

```
<Marker
     key={index}
     onClick={(props, marker, e) => this.onMarkerClick(props, marker, e, index)} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are facing?

You should call the method passing all the parameters:

```
onClick={() => this.onMarkerClick(marker, e, index)}
```

But you can reference props directly:

```
this.onMarkerClick  = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
onMarkerClick = (marker, e, index) => {
        this.setState({
            defaultAnimation: null,
            showingInfoWindow: true,
            activeMarker: marker,
            selectedPlace: this.props
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Laura but this not work for me. I have an error:

Comment: If I put the code this way onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {) <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} /> the code works properly. But I need to pass the index.